# Performance of groupby when dealing with `category` type in pandas

Tags: python, performance, pandas, categories

I would like to understand the subtlety behind the usage of `category` in pandas.

I created a random three columns DataFrame through

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.random.choice(['a', 'A'], size=100000)
b = np.random.choice(range(10000), size=100000)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(A1=a, A2=a, B=b))
df['A2'] = df.A2.astype('category')
```

treating `A2` has a `category` type column.

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 100000 entries, 0 to 99999
Data columns (total 3 columns):
A1    100000 non-null object
A2    100000 non-null category
B     100000 non-null int64
dtypes: category(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 1.6+ MB
```

Running a `groupby` operator on `B` and applying a simple function on both `A1` and `A2` leads to a dramatic difference in terms of performance,

```
%%timeit
df_ = df.groupby(by='B').agg(
    dict(
        A1=lambda s: len(s.unique())
    )
)

1 loop, best of 3: 666 ms per loop
```

and

```
%%timeit
df_ = df.groupby(by='B').agg(
    dict(
        A2=lambda s: len(s.unique())
    )
)

1 loop, best of 3: 2.73 s per loop
```

Could you please enlighten me on the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use rather [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html), it works with `category` only a little bit slowier:

```
print (df.groupby(by='B')['A1'].nunique())
print (df.groupby(by='B')['A2'].nunique())

In [71]: %timeit (df.groupby(by='B')['A1'].nunique())
10 loops, best of 3: 19.8 ms per loop

In [72]: %timeit (df.groupby(by='B')['A2'].nunique())
10 loops, best of 3: 20.2 ms per loop
```

Interesting, if use `agg` with `dict`, performance is same:

```
In [77]: %timeit df.groupby(by='B').agg({'A1':'nunique'})
100 loops, best of 3: 20.1 ms per loop

In [78]: %timeit df.groupby(by='B').agg({'A2':'nunique'})
10 loops, best of 3: 20.1 ms per loop
```

but if use `lambda` function, `dtype` `category` is more slowier (same problem as you):

```
In [73]: %timeit df.groupby(by='B').agg(dict(A1=lambda s: s.nunique()))
1 loop, best of 3: 824 ms per loop

In [74]: %timeit df.groupby(by='B').agg(dict(A2=lambda s: s.nunique()))
1 loop, best of 3: 3.07 s per loop
```

Comment: Thank you for this piece of advice. Any hint on the reason behind the 'poor performance' of `lambda`?

Comment: Hard question, maybe you can try ask in [`github`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues), because it looks like bug.

Comment: The pandas team answered on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13734).